# username password to set the connection in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tried every username/password such as hr, SYS, SYSTEM and the one that I used while installing the database but none of them worked, can someone please correct me if I am using a wrong approach I have attached the screenshot as well [image]

Comment: Are you talking about the client side or the server install?

Comment: Thank you for responding, I am new to this I have just downloaded oracle sql  developer from oracle .com and installed the software and now for my practice I want to create a connection

Comment: A connection to what though? SQL Developer is a client. You need a database to connect to; either an existing one you already have details for, or one you create with [the Oracle *server* software](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html), or [a pre-built developer VM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vms-192663.html).

Comment: But I am not able to create one as it is not accepting the username password

Comment: [I have Oracle SQL Developer Installed, Now What?](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/12/i-have-oracle-sql-developer-installed-now-what/)

Comment: nos how can I create a connection in it to create the DB

Comment: You have to create the database first, as explained in the link above; then you can create a connection to it. Not the other way around.

Comment: @AlexPoole I have added the error screenshot, could you please suggest on the same?

Comment: Gs650x: Have you gone through the links Alex shared? Please understand that this isn't like SQL server's create database. In Oracle, creating a db means you must download and install Oracle database separately inorder to be able to connect. SQL developer will not help you to create a database in your local

Comment: @gs650x. SQL Developer is just a front end tool that connects to a database. If all you have done is installed SQL Developer, that will not on its own give you a database. You would need to download and install the Oracle database software - Oracle Express is recommended for local use. During the install of that it creates a database, with the default credentials and details you have tried.

Comment: @gs650x, can you check whether your database is up and running? I think you have installed the database but not started it. Hence you are getting `The Network Adapter could not establish the connection` error.